# Adapt Custom hover card on Lists for Sharepoint

Tags: json, if-statement, sharepoint-online

I just tried to adapt "Custom hover card on Lists" from Github to my Sharepoint online list but ran into a couple of issues (https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/column-samples/custom-hover-cards).

Basically, I'd like to have this hover card list to work for my simple process:

1. Start
2. In progress
3. Done

Is there anyone who could support me in this?

Thanks in advance & BR
Henri

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "font-size": "12px"
  },
  "txtContent": "[$Status]",
  "customCardProps": {
    "formatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "padding": "15px 45px 15px 15px"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "18px",
                        "font-weight": "550",
                        "text-align": "center",
                        "margin-bottom": "10px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": "Tracking details"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "16px",
                        "font-weight": "600",
                        "padding-left": "15px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": " ",
                      "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "StatusCircleCheckmark",
                        "class": "ms-fontColor-green"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "16px",
                        "font-weight": "600",
                        "margin-left": "-16px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": " ",
                      "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "CircleRing",
                        "class": "ms-fontColor-green"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "=if([$StatusCode] > 0, '16px', ''",
                        "font-weight": "=if([$StatusCode] > 0, '600', ''",
                        "padding-left": "9px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": "Ready to be packed",
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 0, 'green', 'green')"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "10px",
                        "font-weight": "600",
                        "text-align": "center"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 0, 'black', 'black')"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "border-left-style": "solid",
                        "border-left-color": "='ms-borderColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 0,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')",
                        "text-align": "center",
                        "margin-left": "21px"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 0,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "16px",
                        "font-weight": "600",
                        "padding-left": "15px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": " ",
                      "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "=if([$StatusCode] > 0, 'StatusCircleCheckmark', 'CircleRing')",
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 0,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "16px",
                        "font-weight": "600",
                        "margin-left": "-16px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": " ",
                      "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "CircleRing",
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 0,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "=if([$StatusCode] > 0, '16px', ''",
                        "font-weight": "=if([$StatusCode] > 0, '600', ''",
                        "padding-left": "9px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": "Packed",
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 0,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "10px",
                        "font-weight": "600",
                        "text-align": "center",
                        "border-left-style": "solid",
                        "border-left-color": "=if([$StatusCode] > 1,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')",
                        "margin-left": "21px"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 0, 'black', 'black')"
                      },
                      "txtContent": "[$PackedDate]"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "border-left-style": "solid",
                        "border-left-color": "='ms-borderColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 1,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')",
                        "margin-left": "21px"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 1,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "16px",
                        "font-weight": "600",
                        "padding-left": "15px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": " ",
                      "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "=if([$StatusCode] > 1, 'StatusCircleCheckmark', 'CircleRing')",
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 1,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "16px",
                        "font-weight": "600",
                        "margin-left": "-16px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": " ",
                      "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "CircleRing",
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 1,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "=if([$StatusCode] > 1, '16px', ''",
                        "font-weight": "=if([$StatusCode] > 1, '600', ''",
                        "padding-left": "9px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": "Shipped",
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 1,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "10px",
                        "font-weight": "600",
                        "text-align": "center",
                        "border-left-style": "solid",
                        "border-left-color": "= if([$StatusCode] > 2,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')",
                        "margin-left": "21px"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 1, 'black', 'black')"
                      },
                      "txtContent": "[$ShippedDate]"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "border-left-style": "solid",
                        "border-left-color": "='ms-borderColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 2,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')",
                        "margin-left": "21px"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 2,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "16px",
                        "font-weight": "600",
                        "padding-left": "15px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": " ",
                      "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "=if([$StatusCode] > 2, 'StatusCircleCheckmark', 'CircleRing')",
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 2,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "16px",
                        "font-weight": "600",
                        "margin-left": "-16px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": " ",
                      "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "CircleRing",
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 2,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "=if([$StatusCode] > 2, '16px', ''",
                        "font-weight": "=if([$StatusCode] > 2, '600', ''",
                        "padding-left": "9px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": "In transit",
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 2,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "10px",
                        "font-weight": "600",
                        "text-align": "center",
                        "border-left-style": "solid",
                        "border-left-color": "=if([$StatusCode] > 3,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')",
                        "margin-left": "21px"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 2, 'black', 'black')"
                      },
                      "txtContent": "[$InTransitStartDate]"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "border-left-style": "solid",
                        "border-left-color": "='ms-borderColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 3,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')",
                        "margin-left": "21px"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 3,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "16px",
                        "font-weight": "600",
                        "padding-left": "15px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": " ",
                      "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "=if([$StatusCode] > 3, 'StatusCircleCheckmark', 'CircleRing')",
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 3,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "16px",
                        "font-weight": "600",
                        "margin-left": "-16px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": " ",
                      "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "CircleRing",
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 3,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "span",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "=if([$StatusCode] > 3, '16px', ''",
                        "font-weight": "=if([$StatusCode] > 3, '600', ''",
                        "padding-left": "9px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": "Delivered",
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 3,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "style": {
                        "font-size": "10px",
                        "font-weight": "600",
                        "text-align": "center",
                        "margin-left": "21px"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 3, 'black', 'black')"
                      },
                      "txtContent": "[$DeliveredDate]"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "openOnEvent": "hover",
    "directionalHint": "bottomCenter",
    "isBeakVisible": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish hover card:

```
     Step 1: You need to create a choice column named as "Status" with options as Start,In progress,Done

     Step 2: You need to create a choice column named as "Status Code" with options as 1,2,3 where 1(represents Start),2 (In Progress),3 (Done). Set Number Accordingly.
```

Add the following JSON in your column formatting . Result of following JSON:
[image]
Now add the following JSON in you Column formatting:

{
"elmType": "div",
"style": {
"font-size": "12px"
},
"txtContent": "[$Status]",
"customCardProps": {
"formatter": {
"elmType": "div",
"children": [
{
"elmType": "div",
"children": [
{
"elmType": "div",
"style": {
"padding": "15px 45px 15px 15px"
},
"children": [
{
"elmType": "div",
"children": [
{
"elmType": "div",
"style": {
"font-size": "18px",
"font-weight": "550",
"text-align": "center",
"margin-bottom": "10px"
},
"txtContent": "Status Tracking"
}
]
},
{
"elmType": "div",
"children": [
{
"elmType": "span",
"style": {
"border-left-style": "solid",
"border-left-color": "='ms-borderColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 0,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')",
"text-align": "center",
"margin-left": "21px"
},
"attributes": {
"class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 0,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
}
}
]
},
{
"elmType": "div",
"children": [
{
"elmType": "span",
"style": {
"font-size": "16px",
"font-weight": "600",
"padding-left": "15px"
},
"txtContent": " ",
"attributes": {
"iconName": "=if([$StatusCode] > 0, 'StatusCircleCheckmark', 'CircleRing')",
"class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 0,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
}
},
{
"elmType": "span",
"style": {
"font-size": "16px",
"font-weight": "600",
"margin-left": "-16px"
},
"txtContent": " ",
"attributes": {
"iconName": "CircleRing",
"class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 0,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
}
},
{
"elmType": "span",
"style": {
"font-size": "=if([$StatusCode] > 0, '16px', ''",
"font-weight": "=if([$StatusCode] > 0, '600', ''",
"padding-left": "9px"
},
"txtContent": "Start",
"attributes": {
"class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 0,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
}
},
{
"elmType": "div",
"style": {
"font-size": "10px",
"font-weight": "600",
"text-align": "center",
"border-left-style": "solid",
"border-left-color": "=if([$StatusCode] > 1,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')",
"margin-left": "21px"
},
"attributes": {
"class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 0, 'black', 'black')"
},
"txtContent": "[$PackedDate]"
}
]
},
{
"elmType": "div",
"children": [
{
"elmType": "span",
"style": {
"border-left-style": "solid",
"border-left-color": "='ms-borderColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 1,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')",
"margin-left": "21px"
},
"attributes": {
"class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 1,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
}
}
]
},
{
"elmType": "div",
"children": [
{
"elmType": "span",
"style": {
"font-size": "16px",
"font-weight": "600",
"padding-left": "15px"
},
"txtContent": " ",
"attributes": {
"iconName": "=if([$StatusCode] > 1, 'StatusCircleCheckmark', 'CircleRing')",
"class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 1,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
}
},
{
"elmType": "span",
"style": {
"font-size": "16px",
"font-weight": "600",
"margin-left": "-16px"
},
"txtContent": " ",
"attributes": {
"iconName": "CircleRing",
"class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 1,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
}
},
{
"elmType": "span",
"style": {
"font-size": "=if([$StatusCode] > 1, '16px', ''",
"font-weight": "=if([$StatusCode] > 1, '600', ''",
"padding-left": "9px"
},
"txtContent": "In Progress",
"attributes": {
"class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 1,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
}
},
{
"elmType": "div",
"style": {
"font-size": "10px",
"font-weight": "600",
"text-align": "center",
"border-left-style": "solid",
"border-left-color": "= if([$StatusCode] > 2,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')",
"margin-left": "21px"
},
"attributes": {
"class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 1, 'black', 'black')"
},
"txtContent": "[$ShippedDate]"
}
]
},
{
"elmType": "div",
"children": [
{
"elmType": "span",
"style": {
"border-left-style": "solid",
"border-left-color": "='ms-borderColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 2,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')",
"margin-left": "21px"
},
"attributes": {
"class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 2,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
}
}
]
},
{
"elmType": "div",
"children": [
{
"elmType": "span",
"style": {
"font-size": "16px",
"font-weight": "600",
"padding-left": "15px"
},
"txtContent": " ",
"attributes": {
"iconName": "=if([$StatusCode] > 2, 'StatusCircleCheckmark', 'CircleRing')",
"class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 2,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
}
},
{
"elmType": "span",
"style": {
"font-size": "16px",
"font-weight": "600",
"margin-left": "-16px"
},
"txtContent": " ",
"attributes": {
"iconName": "CircleRing",
"class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 2,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
}
},
{
"elmType": "span",
"style": {
"font-size": "=if([$StatusCode] > 2, '16px', ''",
"font-weight": "=if([$StatusCode] > 2, '600', ''",
"padding-left": "9px"
},
"txtContent": "Done",
"attributes": {
"class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 2,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')"
}
},
{
"elmType": "div",
"style": {
"font-size": "10px",
"font-weight": "600",
"text-align": "center",
"border-left-style": "solid",
"border-left-color": "=if([$StatusCode] > 3,'green','neutralSecondaryAlt')",
"margin-left": "21px"
},
"attributes": {
"class": "='ms-fontColor-' + if([$StatusCode] > 2, 'black', 'black')"
},
"txtContent": "[$InTransitStartDate]"
}
]
}
]
}
]
}
]
},
"openOnEvent": "hover",
"directionalHint": "bottomCenter",
"isBeakVisible": true
}
}

Please don't forget to mark the answer. Thanks